# Facebook : How to send a private message as a fanpage using xmpp

Tags: python, facebook, api, xmpp

After days searching unsuccessfully for a solution to my problem, I've decided to ask for help.

I'm trying to send a private message to a facebook user as my fan page using XMPP protocol with python.

I'm using the code below to create the client:

```
import sleekxmpp

class SendMsgBot(sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP):
    def __init__(self, jid, recipient, message):
        sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP.__init__(self, jid, 'ignore')
        self.recipient = recipient
        self.msg = message
        self.add_event_handler("session_start", self.start, threaded=True)

    def start(self, event):
        self.send_presence()
        self.get_roster()
        self.send_message(mto=self.recipient,
        mbody=self.msg,
        mtype='chat')
        self.disconnect(wait=True)
```

This is the code where I use the client created above to send the message:

```
from fbxmpp import SendMsgBot

jid = '1000021...@chat.facebook.com'
to = '1351...@chat.facebook.com'
msg = 'Hey  anything , how is it going?'

xmpp = SendMsgBot(jid, to, unicode(msg))

xmpp.credentials['api_key'] = '599641.....' 
xmpp.credentials['access_token'] = 'CAACEdEose0cBACVTezXXZATDZAZBucX8fTUB0a....'

if xmpp.connect(('chat.facebook.com', 5222)):
    xmpp.process(block=True)
    print("Done")
else:
    print("Unable to connect.")
```

Using my facebook login and password in the code above,  I don't get any error. But I need to send the message using my **fan page**.

I got successfully authenticated with my api_key and access_token, but the console freezes for a while with the following message:

```
DEBUG:sleekxmpp.xmlstream.xmlstream:RECV: <success xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl" />
DEBUG:sleekxmpp.xmlstream.xmlstream:Event triggered: auth_success
DEBUG:sleekxmpp.xmlstream.xmlstream:SEND (IMMED): <stream:stream to='chat.facebook.com' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' xmlns='jabber:client' xml:lang='en' version='1.0'>
DEBUG:sleekxmpp.xmlstream.xmlstream:RECV: <stream:stream version="1.0" from="chat.facebook.com" id="1" xml:lang="en">
DEBUG:sleekxmpp.xmlstream.xmlstream:RECV: <stream:features xmlns="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind" /><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session" /></stream:features>
DEBUG:sleekxmpp.features.feature_bind.bind:Requesting resource: 
DEBUG:sleekxmpp.xmlstream.xmlstream:SEND (IMMED): <iq type="set" id="6e6fe59f-1683-41a9-9a32-dc8a952cdecd-2"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind" /></iq>
DEBUG:sleekxmpp.xmlstream.xmlstream:RECV: <iq type="result" from="-100002126842229@chat.facebook.com" id="6e6fe59f-1683-41a9-9a32-dc8a952cdecd-2"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><jid>-100002126842229@chat.facebook.com/xymAXUKM</jid></bind></iq>
```

And after the timeout I got this other message:

```
WARNING:sleekxmpp.xmlstream.handler.waiter:Timed out waiting for IqWait_6e6fe59f-1683-41a9-9a32-dc8a952cdecd-2
ERROR:sleekxmpp.xmlstream.xmlstream:Error processing stream handler: Stream Features
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/felipecabral/.virtualenvs/facebook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sleekxmpp/xmlstream/xmlstream.py", line 1669, in _event_runner
    handler.run(args[0])
  File "/Users/felipecabral/.virtualenvs/facebook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sleekxmpp/xmlstream/handler/callback.py", line 76, in run
    self._pointer(payload)
  File "/Users/felipecabral/.virtualenvs/facebook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sleekxmpp/clientxmpp.py", line 280, in _handle_stream_features
    if handler(features) and restart:
  File "/Users/felipecabral/.virtualenvs/facebook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sleekxmpp/features/feature_bind/bind.py", line 50, in _handle_bind_resource
    response = iq.send(now=True)
  File "/Users/felipecabral/.virtualenvs/facebook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sleekxmpp/stanza/iq.py", line 230, in send
    raise IqTimeout(self)
IqTimeout
ERROR:sleekxmpp.xmlstream.stanzabase:Error handling {jabber:client}features stanza
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/felipecabral/.virtualenvs/facebook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sleekxmpp/xmlstream/xmlstream.py", line 1669, in _event_runner
    handler.run(args[0])
  File "/Users/felipecabral/.virtualenvs/facebook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sleekxmpp/xmlstream/handler/callback.py", line 76, in run
    self._pointer(payload)
  File "/Users/felipecabral/.virtualenvs/facebook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sleekxmpp/clientxmpp.py", line 280, in _handle_stream_features
    if handler(features) and restart:
  File "/Users/felipecabral/.virtualenvs/facebook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sleekxmpp/features/feature_bind/bind.py", line 50, in _handle_bind_resource
    response = iq.send(now=True)
  File "/Users/felipecabral/.virtualenvs/facebook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sleekxmpp/stanza/iq.py", line 230, in send
    raise IqTimeout(self)
IqTimeout
```

Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using a very recent version of sleekxmpp? I have a suspicion that this problem might be related to [this change](https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/issues/278) - the error suggests that the library is waiting for the IQ result that it actually received, so maybe it didn't expect the "from" attribute that it got (the bare JID of the user).

Comment: "Very recent" seems to include version 1.2.0.

Comment: The version that is installed in my workon is sleekxmpp == 1.2.3 
Do you believe that installing a previous 1.2 version could solve? Think it's worth taking the test?

Comment: It seems like 1.2.0 is the latest version that doesn't have the change in question. If it works with 1.2.0, this should be reported as a bug in sleekxmpp.

Comment: Thanks it worked. 

Removed the 1.2.3 version and installed version 1.1.11. Now is authenticating using the api and acess_token. 

What I really like to do but still not working, is to send a private message putting my fanpage as the owner of the message but was unable to do so. 

Thank you, I will continue searching the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mentioned over at Github](https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/issues/278#issuecomment-35128631), this should be fixed in sleekxmpp 1.2.4.